# Messages between agents in Anylogic GIS environment

Tags: gis, anylogic

In the Anylogic GIS environment, I want to send a message to the agents that are close to the agent that sends the message.
Is it possible to send a message to more than one agent within a certain distance in a GIS environment?

Thanks,

I used send("msg", this.getNearestAgent(agents)); but it only sends the message to the one nearest agent and not the nearest ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own function for this. I created the following one with the agent type called `MyAgent` so replace `MyAgent` with whatever Agent Type you are using:

```
for( MyAgent m : myAgents ) {

    if( agent.distanceTo(m) < 1000000 && agent != m ) { 
        send("msg", m);
    }
}
```

Note that `distanceTo` returns a distance in meters. I also the second condition in the if statement to make sure the agent doesn't send a message to itself. Finally, make sure to add an argument to your function as shown below.

[image]